# NSURLSession download task failing after it already succeeded

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I am experiencing a strange issue from time to with my NSURLSessionDownloadTasks (using a background download configuration).

It is always related to errors with NSURLDomain code NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionWasDisconnected (-997). The error itself usually seems to be coming from the app generically crashing or being forcefully closed during development from Xcode.

The relevant code boils down to

```
- (void)download:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self.urlSession downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
    [downloadTask resume];
}

- (void)       URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
             downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)tempLocation
{
    NSLog(@"task %@ didFinishDownloadingToURL with status code %@", downloadTask, @([downloadTask.response statusCode]));
}

- (void)  URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
                task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"task %@ didCompleteWithError %@", task, error);
}
```

The problem in these cases is, that the same NSURLSessionDownloadTask gets two (instead of only one expected) call in `-[NSURLSessionTaskDelegate URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]`. Once without an error (which aligns to a call with a 200 OK response code to `-[NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:]`) and then another time, usually a couple seconds later **with** an error (-997). Both times it's exactly the same memory address for the task being passed into these delegate methods.

Has anybody else experienced something similar? I am not expecting that second callback after I was already told that my task succeeded. Is there any obvious reason why the NSURLSession may still hold on to a task it reportedly finished already but then all of a sudden thinks it should inform me that it's lost connectivity to it background transfer service?

Comment: Are the `identifier` properties the same, too? I've definitely seen multiple calls come in when dealing with background sessions, but they were always result of previous background sessions from prior, incomplete sessions. (We're so used to starting from a clean state when restarting after crash, but with background sessions, the old tasks are often lingering about.) But, I'm surprised that the memory address for the task is really identical...

Comment: `identifier` is identical and these callbacks should stem from a prior, incomplete session (due to the crash / force quit involved in getting to this behavior).

Comment: I don't suppose that 8 years later you remember what you learned was happening? I'm getting similar behavior...

Comment: We never really got to the bottom of this unfortunately. Ultimately we decided that what we needed to do (download up to hundreds of individual files in the background) wasn't suited for "true" background downloads. So we discarded this approach and instead went with only the 2 minute window you get after suspending the app and no true background downloads. Not that great for the users, much better and simpler in many other regards (eg ability to prioritize etc).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had a similar issue because I was updating the UI from the NSURLSession delegate methods, which run in background thread.

So, the solution for me was to move the UI-related code to run on the main thread as below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      //code updating the UI.
});
```